# Communicating over Serial to an Arduino not working?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

Im trying to power a 360 servo via serial commands
when I use
`servo1.writeMicroseconds(1000);`
the servo turns clockwise at full power, replacing 1000 with 1500 stops it, and 2000 makes it go anticlockwise.

The `Serial.write(val);` to debug also gives a weird answer, when I use the value of 1, the board receives it as:

--> 49
--> 10

Board is an Arduino Mega 2560

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo1;
int val = 1500;

void setup() {
servo1.attach(7);
servo1.writeMicroseconds(val);
Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop(){

if(Serial.available()){ 

int val = Serial.read();
Serial.write(val);
servo1.writeMicroseconds(val);

}
}
```

Comment: `Serial.read()` return the ASCII code of the sent data.  character '1' in ASCII is `49`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Serial.write()`. It's for writing bytes. Instead use `Serial.println(...)` which will print a line and handle multiple input types.

Another recommendation is don't use `Serial.read()` for just integers. Use `Serial.parseInt()` as described [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/parseint/)